# Python Prisma hangs on disconnect() when inside Docker container

Tags: python, docker, prisma

I have a very basic service where I am trying to access a database in Python using the Prisma package. I have a Docker container that I build and run with hypercorn to host the service. When I `find_many()` on the table, it successfully pulls down the information. However, when inside of the Docker container, the service hangs on the `disconnect()` call. When I test locally, it can successfully disconnect. Here is the entire file:

```py
import json
from prisma import Prisma

from quart import Quart

import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('prisma').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = Quart(__name__)


@app.route("/")
async def hello_world():
    projects = None
    print("trying query...")
    async with Prisma() as prisma:
        projects = await prisma.project.find_many()
        print(projects)

    print("query successful")
    return json.dumps(list(map(lambda proj: proj.model_dump_json(), projects)))

# For local testing, enable this line
# app.run()
```

When testing on the Docker container, the last message in the logs is simply `DEBUG:prisma.engine.query:Disconnecting query engine...`. It prints out the projects list, but never prints "query successful", as it hangs on attempting to leave the context manager (which calls `prisma.disconnect()`). Using manual `await prisma.connect()` and `await prisma.disconnect()` calls results in the same thing.

EDIT:
This seems to be a problem exclusive to hypercorn. I switched to using uvicorn, and it worked with no issues.